# How can i make "pygame.event.get()" available across all the modules in pygame

Tags: python, events, module, pygame

So i am making a `pygame` program and for that i have written a `GUI.py` module. One of the classes is Button and one of the methods  of that button is clicked, which basically checks if the button is being pressed. Initially i used `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` to check for mouse press, but the problem i had with that is that it registered multiple presses within a single frame, which is not what i want.

```
def clicked(self):
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()# Gets the position of the mouse 
        mouse_pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()# Checks if the mouse is being pressed
        # checking if the mouse is already inside the button
        if self.mouseover():
            # mouse_pressed[0] returns true if the left mouse button is being pressed
            if mouse_pressed[0]:
                return True
        return False
```

So i need to use events to check for mouse press. However, i am importing `GUI.py` to other modules, which are then imported to `main.py`. Becasue of this, i cannot import `main.py` to `GUI.py`. But `main.py` is where `pygame.event.get()` is being called in the main loop. I could call the method in other modules and pass in events as an argument, but i want to do that every single time i make a button.
Sorry if what i tried to explain is unclear, but here is what the question boils down to. Is there a way to make `pygame.event.get()` available to all the modules in my program independent of everything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i solved this in my [pygame UI module](https://github.com/TheBigKahuna353/PygameUI/blob/master/UI.py#L232) was to store the previous frame click state, so if the mouse was clicked this frame and not last frame, its a click otherwise its being held down and nothing happens. (my module is a bit more complicated as it makes sure you clicked on it, then let go on it to count as a click)

```py
if click and not previous_frame_click:
    #clicked
```

if you are just using a function and not a class to do this, then maybe create a global variable

```
last_frame_click = False

def clicked(self):
    global last_frame_click

    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()# Gets the position of the mouse 
    mouse_pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()# Checks if the mouse is being pressed
    # checking if the mouse is already inside the button
    if self.mouseover():
        # mouse_pressed[0] returns true if the left mouse button is being pressed
        if mouse_pressed[0] and not last_frame_click[0]:
            last_frame_click = mouse_pressed
            return True
    last_frame_click = mouse_pressed
    return False
```

EDIT: just noticed you said one of the classes, dont worry about above code, just use `self.last_frame_click`

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar issue I created an event manager module for it. Anything that wanted to be notified about events would register an event handler with the event manager, providing the events the handler was interested in and a event handler callback.

The event manager was handed the events from the event loop and it would check the events against the registered events. If there was a match then the event manager would call the associated event handler callback passing along the event as an argument to the callback.

It sounds more complicated than it really is.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering but can you add  some code please, i don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and What worked for me was pretty simple. Make a new Module and put this code in it:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

def event_handler():
    events = []
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        events.append(event)

    return events
```

And then your main game loop can look something like this:

```
import pygame
from sys import exit
from Code.globals import screen
from Code.Level import Level
from Code.EventHandler import event_handler
    
pygame.init()
  
Level = Level()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
Level.startup()
   
running = True
while running:
    for event in event_handler():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            exit()
            pygame.quit()
        else:
            pass

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    Level.update()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Everything worked fine for me.